# SSH tunel Connection in R

Tags: sql, r, ssh

I am using python to connect to path sql at my work. In python i use this:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import pandas as pd
import psycopg2

tunnel = SSHTunnelForwarder(
  ('name', 22)
  , ssh_private_key="path_to_ssh"
  , ssh_username="username"
  , remote_bind_address=('path', 5432)
  , local_bind_address = ('XXX.X.X.X', 5431)
  )     
tunnel.start()
con_data = psycopg2.connect(host = 'XXX.X.X.X'
                    , database = "name"
                    , user = "user"
                    , password = "passwd"
                    , port = 5431
                    , sslmode ='require')


def create_df(query, con):
   cur = con.cursor() 
   cur.execute(query)
   df = cur.fetchall()
   colnames = [desc[0] for desc in cur.description]
   cur.close()
   df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=colnames)

  return df

query = '''SELECT * FROM table'''

create_df(query, con_data)
```

In R languge i didnt found anyway to create a connection like above!!!
Have you ever tried this in R?
Please there is a R package to start ssh and create a query connection from sql

Comment: The `ssh` R package might do what you want.

Comment: Frankly, including your username and password as string constants in a file is bad news. I recommend: (1) switching to using *keys*, and one form of `ssh-agent` (e.g., pageant, keepass, windows openssh auth agent); (2) try `ssh::ssh_connect` for the basic connection, and then `ssh::ssh_tunnel` for port-forwarding. https://docs.ropensci.org/ssh/articles/intro.html

Comment: And for me, I use `autossh` outside of R and let R use the connections that are automatically forwarded, instead of trying to manage the forwarding within R. (Perhaps you have specific needs where starting outside of R is not possible?)

Comment: Any progress, Gabriel?

Comment: not much... i didnt create a R toy example